# Sharepoint Error: [COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a site basic definition that uses different master and default pages.  Everything works quite well except for whenever I create a new site based on the definition I receive the following error when browsing to the new site:

```
[COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action. Please try again.]
Please try again.]  
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte& pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocId, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte& pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocId, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder) +219

[SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.]
```

I'm able to work around this by checking out the new master page and checking it back in again and after doing so there are no further issues at all.

Any ideas to what could cause this?

ONET.XML module section:

```
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="CustomMasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
      <File Url="Shoes.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" /> 
    </Module>
    <Module Name="Default" List="116" Url="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" Name="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE">
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="1">
          &lt;webParts&gt;&lt;webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"&gt;&lt;metaData&gt;&lt;type name="BCM.SharePoint.Shoes.ShoesComponents.FooterLinks, BCM.SharePoint.Shoes.ShoesComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2881713f39360b71" /&gt;&lt;importErrorMessage&gt;Cannot import this Web Part.&lt;/importErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/metaData&gt;&lt;data&gt;&lt;properties&gt;&lt;property name="AllowClose" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Width" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="MyProperty" type="string"&gt;Hello SharePoint&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowConnect" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype"&gt;None&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string"&gt;/_layouts/images/BCM_SharePoint_Shoes/wp_FooterLinks.gif&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Description" type="string"&gt;FooterLinks Description&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Hidden" type="bool"&gt;False&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="TitleUrl" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="AllowEdit" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Height" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="MissingAssembly" type="string"&gt;Cannot import this Web Part.&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="HelpUrl" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="Title" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string"&gt;/_layouts/images/BCM_SharePoint_Shoes/wp_FooterLinks.gif&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Direction" type="direction"&gt;NotSet&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate"&gt;Normal&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowHide" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode"&gt;Modeless&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode"&gt;All&lt;/property&gt;&lt;/properties&gt;&lt;/data&gt;&lt;/webPart&gt;&lt;/webParts&gt;
        </AllUsersWebPart>
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="0">
          &lt;webParts&gt;&lt;webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"&gt;&lt;metaData&gt;&lt;type name="BCM.SharePoint.Shoes.ShoesComponents.SubFooterLinks, BCM.SharePoint.Shoes.ShoesComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2881713f39360b71" /&gt;&lt;importErrorMessage&gt;Cannot import this Web Part.&lt;/importErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/metaData&gt;&lt;data&gt;&lt;properties&gt;&lt;property name="AllowClose" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Width" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="MyProperty" type="string"&gt;Hello SharePoint&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowConnect" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype"&gt;None&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string"&gt;/_layouts/images/BCM_SharePoint_Shoes/wp_SubFooterLinks.gif&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Description" type="string"&gt;Shoes home page links (under the hero image)&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Hidden" type="bool"&gt;False&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="TitleUrl" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="AllowEdit" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Height" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="MissingAssembly" type="string"&gt;Cannot import this Web Part.&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="HelpUrl" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="Title" type="string" /&gt;&lt;property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string"&gt;/_layouts/images/BCM_SharePoint_Shoes/wp_SubFooterLinks.gif&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="Direction" type="direction"&gt;NotSet&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate"&gt;Normal&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="AllowHide" type="bool"&gt;True&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode"&gt;Modeless&lt;/property&gt;&lt;property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode"&gt;All&lt;/property&gt;&lt;/properties&gt;&lt;/data&gt;&lt;/webPart&gt;&lt;/webParts&gt;
        </AllUsersWebPart>
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" ID="0" Position="Start" />
      </File>
    </Module>
  </Modules>
```

**LOG OUTPUT:**

```
05/21/2010 12:22:55.11  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72nz    Medium      Videntityinfo::isFreshToken reported failure.    
05/21/2010 12:22:55.19  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yv    Medium      Creating default lists   
05/21/2010 12:22:55.19  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72lp    Medium      Creating directory Lists     
05/21/2010 12:22:55.26  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yf    Medium      Creating list "Master Page Gallery" in web "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test" at URL "_catalogs/masterpage", (setuppath: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\global\lists\mplib")    
05/21/2010 12:22:55.28  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88y1    Medium      No document templates uploaded for list "Master Page Gallery" -- none found for list template "100".     
05/21/2010 12:22:55.28  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72kc    Medium      Failed to find generic XML file at "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\xml\onet.xml", falling back to global site definition.  
05/21/2010 12:22:56.22  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yz    Medium      Creating default modules at URL "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test"     
05/21/2010 12:22:56.22  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8e27    Medium      Ensuring module folder _catalogs/masterpage  
05/21/2010 12:22:56.89  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72h7    Medium      Applying template "SubSite#1" to web at URL "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test".    
05/21/2010 12:22:57.09  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yy    Medium      Activating web-scoped features for template "SubSite#1" at URL "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test"  
05/21/2010 12:22:57.12  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l1c    Medium      Preparing 20 features for activation     
05/21/2010 12:22:57.14  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l1d    Medium      Feature Activation: Batch Activating Features at URL http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test 'AnnouncementsList' (ID: '00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104'), 'ContactsList' (ID: '00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105'), 'CustomList' (ID: '00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100'), 'DataSourceLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110'), 'DiscussionsList' (ID: '00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108'), 'DocumentLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101'), 'EventsList' (ID: '00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106'), 'GanttTasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119'), 'GridList' (ID: '00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120'), 'IssuesList' (ID: '00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100'), 'LinksList' (ID: '00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103'), 'NoCodeWorkflowLibrary' (ID: '00bfe...   
05/21/2010 12:22:57.14* w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l1d    Medium      ...a71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117'), 'PictureLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109'), 'SurveysList' (ID: '00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102'), 'TasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107'), 'WebPageLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18'), 'workflowProcessList' (ID: '00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a'), 'WorkflowHistoryList' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140'), 'XmlFormLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115'), 'TeamCollab' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5'), .    
05/21/2010 12:22:57.15  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l1f    Medium      Feature Activation: Batch Activated Features at URL http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test 'AnnouncementsList' (ID: '00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104'), 'ContactsList' (ID: '00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105'), 'CustomList' (ID: '00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100'), 'DataSourceLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110'), 'DiscussionsList' (ID: '00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108'), 'DocumentLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101'), 'EventsList' (ID: '00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106'), 'GanttTasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119'), 'GridList' (ID: '00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120'), 'IssuesList' (ID: '00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100'), 'LinksList' (ID: '00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103'), 'NoCodeWorkflowLibrary' (ID: '00bfea...   
05/21/2010 12:22:57.15* w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l1f    Medium      ...71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117'), 'PictureLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109'), 'SurveysList' (ID: '00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102'), 'TasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107'), 'WebPageLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18'), 'workflowProcessList' (ID: '00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a'), 'WorkflowHistoryList' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140'), 'XmlFormLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115'), 'TeamCollab' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5'), .     
05/21/2010 12:22:57.15  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         88jb    Medium      Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'RadEditorFeatureRichText' (ID: '747755cd-d060-4663-961c-9b0cc43724e9') at URL http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test.    
05/21/2010 12:22:57.15  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         75fb    Medium      Calling 'FeatureActivated' method of SPFeatureReceiver for Feature 'RadEditorFeatureRichText' (ID: '747755cd-d060-4663-961c-9b0cc43724e9').  
05/21/2010 12:22:57.20  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         75f8    Medium      Feature Activation: Feature 'RadEditorFeatureRichText' (ID: '747755cd-d060-4663-961c-9b0cc43724e9') was activated at URL http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test.     
05/21/2010 12:22:57.51  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yv    Medium      Creating default lists   
05/21/2010 12:22:57.51  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72lp    Medium      Creating directory Lists     
05/21/2010 12:22:57.51  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     Fields                          88yz    Medium      Creating default modules at URL "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test"     
05/21/2010 12:22:57.51  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8e27    Medium      Ensuring module folder _catalogs/masterpage  
05/21/2010 12:22:57.56  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72ix    Medium      Not enough information to determine a list for module "Default". Assuming no list for this module.   
05/21/2010 12:22:57.87  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x18A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72h8    Medium      Successfully applied template "SubSite#1" to web at URL "http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test".    
05/21/2010 12:22:59.48  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x0980  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070057   
05/21/2010 12:23:07.06  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Office Server                   Setup and Upgrade               8u3j    High        Registry key value {SearchThrottled} was not found under registry hive {Software\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0}. Assuming search sku is not throttled.    
05/21/2010 12:23:07.08  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        90gf    Medium      SQL: dbo.proc_MSS_PropagationGetQueryServers     
05/21/2010 12:23:07.09  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8wni    High        Resuming default catalog with reason 'GPR_PROPAGATION' for application 'SharedServices1'...  
05/21/2010 12:23:07.11  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8wnj    High        Resuming anchor text catalog with reason GPR_PROPAGATION' for application 'SharedServices1'...   
05/21/2010 12:23:07.14  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8dvl    Medium      Search application '3c6751cc-37b0-470a-bfa2-bfd0b5635fe1': Provision start addresses in default content source.  
05/21/2010 12:23:07.15  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x106C  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        7hmh    High        exception in SearchUpgradeProvisioner Keyword Config System.InvalidOperationException: jobServerSearchServiceInstance is null     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchUpgradeProvisioner..ctor(SearchServiceInstance searchServiceInstance)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.OSSPrimaryGathererProject.ProvisionContentSources()  
05/21/2010 12:23:29.19  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x0FFC  SharePoint Portal Server        Business Data                   79bv    High        Initiating BDC Cache Invalidation Check in AppDomain 'DefaultDomain'     
05/21/2010 12:23:29.19  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x0FFC  SharePoint Portal Server        Business Data                   79bx    High        Completed BDC Cache Invalidation Check in AppDomain 'DefaultDomain'  
05/21/2010 12:23:45.84  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x08A8  SharePoint Portal Server        SSO                             8inc    Medium      In SSOService::Synch(), sso database conn string:    
05/21/2010 12:23:50.80  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x0F14  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqi    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Starting synchronize for instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SharedServices1'.   
05/21/2010 12:23:50.80  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0884)                       0x0F14  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqj    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Successfully synchronized instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SharedServices1'.  
05/21/2010 12:23:52.31  w3wp.exe (0x1E40)                           0x0980  SharePoint Portal Server        Runtime                         8gp7    Medium      Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1963195510/Root-1-129188762904047141)
```

**EVENT LOG:**

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1310
Date:       21/05/2010
Time:       12:24:51
User:       N/A
Computer:   mmm-DEV-ll
Description:
Event code: 3006 
Event message: A parser error has occurred. 
Event time: 5/21/2010 12:24:51 PM 
Event time (UTC): 5/21/2010 11:24:51 AM 
Event ID: 2661db3360d54081bb0f643b4c4a1d38 
Event sequence: 3549 
Event occurrence: 330 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1963195510/Root-1-129188762904047141 
    Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ 
    Machine name: mmm-DEV-ll 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7744 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: http://server//sites/Shoes/test/_catalogs/masterpage/Shoes.master(104): error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DelegateControl' to 'System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor' 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://mmm-dev-ll/sites/Shoes/test/default.aspx 
    Request path: /sites/Shoes/test/default.aspx 
    User host address: 10.3.3.51 
    User: MAPLE\svc-shp-ll 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 5 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: Could you add some information about how your custom masterpage is being deployed? I have a feeling it is related to SharePoint not being able to find something on the filesystem...

Comment: Also try to find this exception in the log and post the few surrounding lines.  The log is in the 14 hive LOGS folder.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but just in case it might still help someone, I came to find that the odd exception is probably due to a miss-format in the CAML query that is sent to interrogate the list.

In my case, I forgot to add the `/>` tag closing at the end of an `FieldRef` tag.

Here's my stack trace:

```
[COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +349

[SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +40346562
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) +40195455
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() +4292
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetEnumerator() +124
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define a Url for default.aspx in your "Default" module. This is why you have an error in ULS, and is probably also responsible for that SPRequest error.

Second, once you apply the master page to the site (i assume, my manually going to /_layouts/settings.aspx then picking Master Page), does it work? The EventLog error points to a delegate control in there is falling over.

Next, your ULS logs are mentioning that it cannot find an onet.xml in a location where one should never exist - onet.xml is ALWAYS found in 12{or 14}\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates{your template name}\XML.

Next, in the comments you mention the 14 logs folder (SharePoint 2010), yet the error I mention above is pointing to the 12 hive (SharePoint 2007/WSS3).

Once you sort those errors, you might find that it suddenly starts working.